# Firebase Android Retrieve post from user's friends only like facebook home

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to show posts.

Code (from comments):

```
Query sertPosts = postRef.orderByChild("counter"); 
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>() .setQuery(sertPosts , Posts.class).build();
postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
```

But I don't want to show all the posts at 'home page'. I just want to show posts which are posted by current user's friends, just the way facebook does.

This is how I managed friend in my Realtime database .

Current User's friends in Realtime Database is stored in this way:

https://s2.gulfupload.com/i/00095/w15m6qo3n7r1.jpg

And Every post is stored with the uid of User who posted it, in following way:

https://s2.gulfupload.com/i/00095/ntftzphh7iu5.jpg

what is the best way to do so?

Comment: Share the code where you are populating your object list and also where you are modifying it according to the query.

Comment: mm don't sure what code extact u mean

Comment: Query sertPosts = postRef.orderByChild("counter");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                .setQuery(sertPosts , Posts.class).build();

Comment: postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do query to get current user friend ids and store in a list.
and in next query when you set your data to adapter class before that just check if the ids of previous query is present in that. if yes then just show

Comment: thanks for ur answer , I'll try it..can u give an exemple how this query should look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private ArrayList<Contacts> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference(root_path).child(Contacts);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            contactsList.clear();
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // here you can store all the friend list of ids
                }
            }
        }
    });
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, UserViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder userViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final Post post) {
              // from here you can check which posts you can show or not
            if (post.getId.equal(contactsList.get(position).getId)) {
                // just bind ur data here becuase you do not need else condition    
            }
        }
    }
```